# WebDAV plugin for Mozilla Thunderbird stopped providing filelinks for large files

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, attachments, webdav

I need help to let my Mozilla Thunderbird (email client) co-operate again with the "**Filelink provider for WebDAV**" plugin. The purpose of this plugin is to help sending messages with large attached files (> 5Mb). More precisely, the plugins should upload the large file to the WebDAV server and write a link into the message body. Then, the message is sent without the large attachment. After receiving the message, the recipient can download the attachment by clicking on the link.

For some unkown reasons, this extremely useful plugin **stopped working** since a couple of months.
Now, as soon as I attach a large file to a message and I click on the "Link" button (which shows up automatically), an error message appears saying that **it is impossibile to send the file to WebDAV**.
Yet, using other ways (e.g. access from a Linux machine), I can see that the WebDAV server is normally working and accessible, and I can see and download its contents. This makes me suspect that Thunderbird is not able to pass/obtain the access permissions to/from the WebDAV server. Thunderbird version, plugin version and the server did not change since the last working time.

I checked the port forwarding in the router, I checked access permissions with the WebDAV server, I tried to uninstall/reinstall the plugin. But everything seems regularly set and nothing helped. I'm stuck.
For compatibility reasons with other plugins, I would prefer avoiding to update to newer versions of Thunderbird (my current version is 78).